# Binding error with ListView, UserControl, DependencyProperty, ObservableCollection, INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

My binding does not work. I searched for the error but I don't understand how to fix it in my case.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'MyApplication.MyUserControl' and 'MyApplication.Person'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='MyUserControl' (Name=''); target element is 'MyUserControl' (Name=''); target property is 'PersonInfo' (type 'Person')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='MyApplication.MyUserControl' BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='MyUserControl' (Name=''); target element is 'MyUserControl' (Name=''); target property is 'PersonInfo' (type 'Person')

Basically it's a ListView that is bound to a ObservableCollection of the class Person.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonCollection { set; get; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        PersonCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        InitializeComponent();
        PersonCollection.Add(new Person() { Name = "Bob", Age = 20 });
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" xmlns:self="clr-namespace:MyApplication" x:Class="MyApplication.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <self:MyUserControl PersonInfo="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</Window>
```

**MyUserControl.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PersonInfo", typeof(Person), typeof(MyUserControl));

    public Person PersonInfo
    {
        get { return (Person)GetValue(PersonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PersonProperty, value); }
    }

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**MyUserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" x:Class="MyApplication.MyUserControl" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonInfo.Name}" />
</UserControl>
```

**Person.cs**

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Age { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't quite understand why you would make it that complicated. You could easily bind your UserControl without the `PersonInfo` property and without modifying its DataContext.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.MyUserControl" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"> 
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" /> 
</UserControl>
```

Then place the UserControl in a DataTemplate without an explicit binding. Its DataContext will then already contain a Person object.

```
<DataTemplate>      
    <StackPanel>      
        <self:MyUserControl />      
    </StackPanel>      
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you fixed your problem, your entire Binding code seems wrong to me, so I propose this alternative:

Have a base class for all binding source objects - **ObservableObject.cs**

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Have a view model for your MainWindow - **MainWindowModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Person> personCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
    {
        new Person() { Name = "Bob", Age = 20 }
    };

    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonCollection
    {
        get { return this.personCollection; }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** is now basically empty.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml** sets DataContext to new MainWindowModel instance.

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.MainWindow" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:self="clr-namespace:MyApplication">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <self:MainWindowModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <self:MyUserControl/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

**MyUserControl.xaml.cs** is also basically empty (contains only auto-generated code).

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**MyUserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.MyUserControl" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</UserControl>
```

**Person.cs**

```
public class Person : ObservableObject
{
    private int age;
    private string name;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return this.age; }
        set { this.SetValue(ref this.age, value, "Age"); }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.SetValue(ref this.name, value, "Name"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for improving my code and helping me get better, appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Change your UserControl XAML to

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
               Text="{Binding PersonInfo.Name}" />
</UserControl>
```

Here is a [good explanation](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/) for the problem with DataContext.

Comment: See the link I added for further investigation too.